# Why does DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i A', $date)->format('d-m-Y') change the date to the following day after 1pm?

Tags: php, datetime

Why does DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i A', $date)->format('d-m-Y') change the date to the following day after 1pm?

** Note
I think it ma have something to do with the format of 'H' or 'h' 
I'm still trying tot figure it out..

```
    $date = "04-12-2018 12:59 PM";
    $date_input = "04-12-2018 13:00 PM";

    echo $date . ' - date <br>';
    echo $date_input . ' - date_input <br>';

    var_dump($date);
    echo '<br/>';
    var_dump($date_input);
    echo '<br/>';

    echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i A', $date)->format('d-m-Y') . '<br/>';
    echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i A', $date_input)->format('d-m-Y') . '<br/>';
```

Results:

```
04-12-2018 12:59 PM - date

04-12-2018 13:00 PM - date_input 

string(19) "04-12-2018 12:59 PM" 

string(19) "04-12-2018 13:00 PM" 

04-12-2018

05-12-2018
```

Comment: In the 12-hour clock hours go from 1 to 12. There is no "13pm" but if there was, what would it be if not 1am the following day?

Comment: 13:00 PM should be 1pm, I am currently working on testing the A to see if that makes a difference as well as changing around the H

Comment: @TomCurphey have you found a suitable solution in any of those # answers? If not, tell us more. Otherwise do and accept the solution that is best for you to close the question - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 13:00 PM
If you do the format function thinks it's the next day.

Change the code to the solution below:

** Note: $date_input & $another_date with regards to their format 'H or h' & 'A'

```
$date = "04-12-2018 12:59 PM";
$date_input = "04-12-2018 13:00";
$another_date = "04-12-2018 01:00 PM" ;

echo $date . ' - date <br>';
echo $date_input . ' - date_input <br>';
echo $another_date . ' - another_date <br>';

var_dump($date);
echo '<br/>';
var_dump($date_input);
echo '<br/>';
var_dump($another_date);
echo '<br/>';

echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i A', $date)->format('d-m-Y') . '<br/>';
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i', $date_input)->format('d-m-Y') . '<br/>';
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y h:i A', $another_date)->format('d-m-Y') . '<br/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

"13:00 pm" is not a valid time: in the 12 hour clock hours go from 1 to 12. You can check if the parsing failed by calling `DateTime::getLastErrors()`:

```
php > echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i A', $date_input)->format('d-m-Y');
05-12-2018
php > print_r(DateTime::getLastErrors());
Array
(
    [warning_count] => 1
    [warnings] => Array
        (
            [19] => The parsed time was invalid
        )

    [error_count] => 0
    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

It seems that the implementation treats 13pm as 1am, just like it treats "Nov 31" as Dec 1.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PHP documentation of DateTime::__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)

> Non-existent values roll over.

```
// Non-existent values roll over.
$date = new DateTime('2000-02-30');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```

output

```
 2000-03-01 00:00:00-05:00
```

So it is not a bug, it is a feature.